# Updating of many records using Formula field meets any governor limits?

Tags: formula-field, governorlimits, update, record

I am Trying to create **a report on Object__c.**
So I am trying to use user custom field(projectName__c) value in custom object field(projectName__c) in filter in Reports.

For that, I got a **suggestion** to do like below, and filter with Boolean.

Create a formula field in the custom object which is checkbox type and formula will be

```
IF(projectName__c=user.projectName__c,true,false)
```

And create a report where apply filter `forumulaField__c = true`.

So, This is working fine. But When I change projectName__c, The all same projectName__c record's will be updated. If I change it to another project again records will be updated. **I will have 1 Million records in my application,** Presently I am using developer account.

**Does This updating on 1 Million records meets any governor limits?**

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the Indian Numbering System, a Lakh is 100,000 (one hundred thousand). 10 Lakhs is therefore 1,000,000 (one million)

Answer (score 0):

Formula field values are returned on the fly and changing values of formula field doesn't even update `Last Modified Date` (just for an info). *This values are returned whenever it is requested (either through UI or SOQL query or by other ways)*.

> So, changing formula field values will not impact on any governor limits.